# the way of writing command

Tags: boot

I want to cp a directory but I do not want to overwrite any existing files even it they are older than the copied files. And I want to do it completely noniteractive as this will be a part of a Crontab Bash script. Any ideas?
and copy content of file inside file without overwrite ?

Comment: sounds like a cron job `--ignore-existing`

Comment: ...I mean of course *rsync* job :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `cp -n <source> <destination>`. Existing files will not be overwritten.

Answer (score -2):

> ```
> cp -a     archive files
>
> cp -f     force copy by removing the destination file if needed
> ```
>
> cp -i     interactive - ask before overwrite
>
> cp -l     link files instead of copy
>
> cp -L     follow symbolic links
>
> cp -n     no file overwrite
>
> cp -R     recursive copy (including hidden files)
>
> cp -u     update - copy when source is newer than dest
>
> cp -v     verbose - print informative messages